# Merge Multiple JSON Into Single OBject

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have multiple JSON files that I would like to parse, edit, and merge into one object, which will ultimately get re-encoded and output as a single JSON.

I currently have a working example of when I parse and edit one object, but I can't figure out how to do two and get a single result.

Working example:

```
$source = 'http://www.jakedup.com/_/source1';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($source));

// THIS WILL BE THE FINAL OUTPUT OBJECT
$output = new stdClass();

// GET THE ARTICLE DATES AS AN ARRAY
$tracks = get_object_vars($data->tracks);

// LOOPS OVER ARTICLE PUBDATES TO GET THE OUTER OBJECTS
foreach ($tracks as $key=>$val) {
  // LOOPS OVER THE INNER OBJECTS IN EACH ARTICLE PUBDATE
  foreach ($data->tracks->$key as $object) {
    // ADD IT ONTO THE OUTPUT OBJECT WITH "ID" AS PARENT NAME
    $output->{$object->id} = $object;
  }
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Here are my JSON examples. I am providing two examples, but I am looking for a way to merge an infinite number of JSON files dynamically.

JSON Source1:

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "tracks":{
        "1349496000":[
            {
                "id":"25328",
                "is_promo":null,
                "is_feature":null,
                "listens":"1312",
                "downloads":"777"
            },
            {
                "id":"25327",
                "is_promo":null,
                "is_feature":null,
                "listens":"1255",
                "downloads":"578"
            },
            {
                "id":"25329",
                "is_promo":null,
                "is_feature":null,
                "listens":"341",
                "downloads":"139"
            }
        ],
        "1349323200":[
            {
                "id":"25310",
                "is_promo":null,
                "is_feature":null,
                "listens":"10793",
                "downloads":"4953"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

JSON Source 2:

```
{
    "foo":"bar",
    "tracks":{
        "1349323200":[
            {
                "id":"25303",
                "is_promo":null,
                "is_feature":null,
                "listens":"2347",
                "downloads":"1499"
            }
        ],
        "1349236800":[
            {
                "id":"25266",
                "is_promo":null,
                "is_feature":null,
                "listens":"24485",
                "downloads":"19366"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have been toying around with the idea of grabbing sources in a loop, but I am stuck when it gets to merging the data. All my different efforts have not produced the right data structure.

Current test code:

```
$source = 'http://www.jakedup.com/_/source';
$pages = 2;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        $sources[$i] = $source.$i;
        ${'source'.$i} = json_decode(file_get_contents($source.$i));
    }
```

I now have two objects -- $source1 & $source2 -- but I'm not sure what to do next.

This is the output I am expecting:

```
{
    "25328": {
        "id": "25328",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "1312",
        "downloads": "777",
        "timestamp": "1349496000"
    },
    "25327": {
        "id": "25327",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "1255",
        "downloads": "578",
        "timestamp": "1349496000"
    },
    "25329": {
        "id": "25329",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "341",
        "downloads": "139",
        "timestamp": "1349496000"
    },
    "25310": {
        "id": "25310",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "10793",
        "downloads": "4953",
        "timestamp": "1349323200"
    },
    "25303": {
        "id": "25303",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "2347",
        "downloads": "1499",
        "timestamp": "1349323200"
    },
    "25266": {
        "id": "25266",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "24485",
        "downloads": "19366",
        "timestamp": "1349236800"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: so you want to create an array without key?

Comment: Sorry, my first question, was kind of vague. I updated the question with a lot more details and code examples of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little more simply done with a PHP array rather than trying to build the `stdClass` object with numeric properties. `json_encode()` will automatically produce an object `{}` as opposed to an array `[]` if the PHP array has non-consecutive, non-zero based keys.  Likewise [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has an optional second parameter to produce an associative array rather than an object.  So I would recommend decoding the files as an array and looping over them, appending each `id` onto an output array, which you will ultimately `json_encode()` again.

Your code implies that you have JSON source files like 'http://www.jakedup.com/_/source1'.  You were on the right track, but instead of populating new variable variables, retrieve and decode each file in a loop, and append it directly to the output array.

```
// 5 source numbers, don't have to be consecutive
$sources = array(1,2,3,4,5);
// Output array to be encoded as JSON
$output = array();

// Loop over all the source files, retrieve them and add tracks onto the output    
foreach ($sources as $sourcenum) {
  $source = "http://www.jakedup.com/_/source$sourcenum";
  $source_json = file_get_contents($source);

  // Decode it as an associative array, passing TRUE as second param
  $source_array = json_decode($source_json, TRUE);

  // Now loop over the tracks (which are an array) and append each to the output
  // the original key looks like a timestamp
  foreach ($source_array['tracks'] as $timestamp => $ts) {
    foreach ($ts as $track) {
      // Add the track id to $output as a key
      // This doesn't check if the id already exists...
      // if it does, it will just be overwritten with this one
      $output[$track['id']] = $track;
      // Optionally, save the original timestamp key into the track array
      // Maybe you don't care about this
      $output[$track['id']]['timestamp'] = $timestamp;
    }
  }
}

// Look over your array
var_dump($output);

// Finally, re-encode the whole thing back to JSON
// using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (even though it shouldn't be necessary)
$output_json = json_encode($output, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

#### JSON output:

```
{
    "25328": {
        "id": "25328",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "1312",
        "downloads": "777",
        "timestamp": 1349496000
    },
    "25327": {
        "id": "25327",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "1255",
        "downloads": "578",
        "timestamp": 1349496000
    },
    "25329": {
        "id": "25329",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "341",
        "downloads": "139",
        "timestamp": 1349496000
    },
    "25310": {
        "id": "25310",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "10793",
        "downloads": "4953",
        "timestamp": 1349323200
    },
    "25303": {
        "id": "25303",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "2347",
        "downloads": "1499",
        "timestamp": 1349323200
    },
    "25266": {
        "id": "25266",
        "is_promo": null,
        "is_feature": null,
        "listens": "24485",
        "downloads": "19366",
        "timestamp": 1349236800
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a chance to run the code and I got the following:  "PHP Warning:  json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in /public_html/_/fetch_json.php"  -- The code also produced no output. SO I changed the last line to  "$output_json = json_encode($output);"  and I was able to get an output, but the data structure was all wrong, and it seems like a lot of information is missing. This is what I get: {"":{"0":{"id":"25266","is_promo":null,"is_feature":null,"listens":"24485","downloads":"19366"},"timestamp":1349236800}} -- Where did all the data go!?

Comment: I updated my question with the expected output, just so you can get an idea of what I am looking for. The output structure should be identical to the working example code.

Comment: JSON_FORCE_OBJECT is PHP 5.3+. I didn't notice that each of the timestamp properties in your object is a one-element array, so it needs to be `$track[0]['id']` as I added above.

Comment: Updated code works based on testing with second json file alone.

Comment: Thank you again sir! This worked perfectly. Was able to omit the part about JSON_FORCE_OBJECT since I'm too lazy to upgrade to PHP 5.3